# Proving that $V=\operatorname{null}\phi \oplus \{au:a\in\mathbb{F}\}$, where $u$ is not in $\operatorname{null}\phi$

Tags: linear-algebra

This question is from Sheldon Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right*, chapter 3, problem 29.

Suppose $\phi \in \mathrm{L}(V,\mathbb{F})$. Suppose $u\in V$ is not in $\operatorname{null}\phi$. Prove that 
$$V=\operatorname{null}\phi \oplus \{au:a\in\mathbb{F}\}$$

I showed that the intersection $\operatorname{null} \phi \cap \{au:a\in\mathbb{F}\}$ has only the zero of $\mathbb{F}$. 
Now, it is left to show that every $v\in V$ can be written as a sum of two vectors one in $\operatorname{null} \phi$ while the other in $ \{au:a\in\mathbb{F}\}$. 
Let $v\in V$. So, there are two cases, one is where $T(v)=0$ which then $v\in \operatorname{null} \phi $ and $v=v+0u$. The second case is where $T(v)\neq 0$, but how one can deduce that $v\in\{au:a\in\mathbb{F}\}$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

You don't have to consider two cases: observe that for any $v\in V$, you have $\;\phi(v)=\phi(v)\phi(u)\phi(u^{-1})$, hence 
$$\phi(v)=\phi\bigl(\phi(v)\phi(u^{-1})u\bigr).$$
Now write
$$v=\bigl(v-\phi(v)\phi(u)^{-1}u\bigr)+\phi(v)\phi(u)^{-1}u. $$

Comment: The hint above is not correct because the symbol $u^{-1}$ has no meaning for $u$ an element of a typical vector space $V$.

Comment: Oh! yes. I meant $\phi(u)^{-1}$. Typo fixed. Thank you for pointing it!

Answer (score 1):

You want to show that $v=z+au$, for some $z\in\operatorname{null}\phi$. Then
$$
\phi(v)=\phi(z)+a\phi(u)=a\phi(u)
$$
Since $\phi(u)\ne0$, you have the solution for $a$; next prove that, with this choice for $a$,
$$
z=v-au\in\operatorname{null}\phi
$$

---

*Side note.* If the space $V$ is finite dimensional, proving the intersection is trivial suffices.